# Mysql Syntax Error with = any or in

Tags: mysql

I keep getting this error with this delete. Mysql version is 5.0.77. I can't think of anything else that is the issue. I even created a temp table to avoid the issue of modifying tables in the select. :(

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE e.eid IN
       (SELECT *
       FROM    (SELECT w.eid
               FROM' at line 3

with the following delete

```
DELETE
FROM emp2 e
WHERE e.eid IN
       (SELECT *
       FROM    (SELECT w.eid
               FROM    works2 w,
                       emp2 e2,
                       dept2 d
               WHERE   w.did = d.did
               AND     d.managerid = e2.eid
               AND     e.salary > e2.salary
               )
               AS temp1
       );
```

Comment: Fixed the match up. Sorry about that. it was a copy and paste error. I still get the error though

Comment: Have you tried running your queries from the inside out? Does the most nested `select` work on it's own? What about when you try to run both `select`s?

Comment: yea it works when i get rid of the last join. Both selects do

Answer (score 1):

Try losing the alias from the table you are deleting from:

```
DELETE FROM emp2
WHERE eid IN (SELECT ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
DELETE e
FROM emp2 e
  JOIN works2 w
    ON w.eid = e.eid 
  JOIN dept2 d
    ON w.did = d.did
  JOIN emp2 e2
    ON d.managerid = e2.eid
WHERE e.salary > e2.salary
```

or an `EXISTS` version:

```
DELETE FROM emp2 e
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM   works2 w,
               emp2 e2,
               dept2 d
        WHERE  w.did = d.did
          AND  d.managerid = e2.eid
          AND  e.salary > e2.salary
          AND  w.eid = e.eid
      )
```

What exactly are you trying to delete?

Comment: The first one works. I was trying to use an in or =any to get every time the eid's match.

Comment: for the first one, what would happen if there were two emps that needed to be deleted? Would it just pick one? That was why I was trying to go with a = any or in to get one or more cases

Comment: Sorry, I can't test today but I think if there are more than one matching rows, all of them will be deleted.